# Sub-components in Vue functional components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

As I was playing around with functional components in Vue, I realized that the `components` property isn't supported to declare sub-components for functional components. Trying do so will result in an `Unknown custom element` exception.

Except for using global components, is there any way to use sub-components in functional components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit of a workaround, but this [Github comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7492#issuecomment-379570456) suggest using `inject` instead to inject the component.

```
<template functional>
  <div>
    <component :is="injections.components.SomeChildren"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SomeChildren from "./SomeChildren.vue";
export default {
  inject: {
    components: {
      default: {
        SomeChildren
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Not as simple as for regular components, but it does the job.